# How to call more then one layouts in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class UserSignupController < ApplicationController

  layout "signup", only: [:signup]
  layout "user_sessions", only: [:thanks]

  def signup
  end

  def thanks
  end
end
```

I have two different layouts. I want to call signup layout for signup.It can works fine. But when i give two layouts it crashes my code. Is it possible to give like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the layout in each action if you want to use separate ones. So for example

```
def signup
    render "signup", layout: "signup"
end

def thanks
    render "thanks", layout: "thanks"
end
```

That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to set the layout and put under private.

```
class UserSignupController < ApplicationController
  layout :specific_layout

  def signup
  end

  def thanks
  end

  private

  def specific_layout
    case action_name
    when "signup"
      "signup"
    when "thanks"
      "user_sessions"
    else
      "otherlayout"
    end
  end
end
```